# Clearing cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I've encountered a weird thing in WP WooCommerce and I can't understand nor fix it myself.

Thing is I've added a clear button in my checkout page,
that button redirects me to my homepage and adds a ?clear param.
Then I check if that param is set and if it is set then the cart is cleared;

Code:

```
if(isset($_POST["clear_cart"]))
{
    header("Location: https://examplepage.com?clear");
}

add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );

function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() 
{
    global $woocommerce;

    if(isset( $_GET['clear'])) 
    {
         $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
    }
}
```

Now the bug/error thing.

This code works... Once. I'll do my best to explain now.
When I click the clear button for the first time - it works. 
I'm being redirected to my homepage, cart is cleared, everything works.

When I go and add some products again and then I clear the cart
I get redirected to my homepage again (first 4 lines of code)
but my cart isn't cleared now. To get it cleared I have to change my param to something like

```
?clear=true
```

Then I do the same thing and after clicking clear cart button it redirects me again and the cart isn't cleared. If I again change the param to

```
?clear=true
```

it doesn't work this time - because it worked before. Changing the param to

```
?clear=true1
```

clears the cart.

I hope you've already understand what I'm talking about.
I've tried various params instead of "clear" and everytime the same thing happens.

When I also tried echoing something within

```
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url()
```

it also worked only once. I'm out of ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: why you redirect user first and then clear cart, just add ajax call on clear cart button and clear cart in ajax when response come, redirect user to home page .

Comment: You are right, that has been changed already. But it still doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Same stuff happens - I get redirected to my homepage, cart is somewhat cleared (it shows that I still have some products in my cart but when I go to check them it says it's empty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
  global $woocommerce;
  if(isset($_POST["clear_cart"]))
  {
    $data= $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
    if(is_null($data) == 1 ){
     wp_redirect( site_url() ); 
     exit; 
  }
}
```

Assuming your html code is something like below :

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="submit" name="clear_cart" value="1"> 
</form>
```

Comment: It works only when I go to the cart checkout page again.

Comment: Weird thing is it always redirects me properly so the code inside the if statement runs but cart isn't cleared anyway.

Comment: It works much better - cart is cleared instantly but I'm not redirected to my homepage, that means $data is false

Comment: so where you wish to redirect user once cart is empty

Comment: Back to the homepage I guess

Comment: No what is your home url i mean to say does it xyz.com/home ?

Comment: It's simply examplepage.com

Comment: go to your database of wordpress check wp_option table and search for site_url and let me know the value.

Comment: i changed the code instead of home url now user is going to redirect on site url . as site url is always your home url.

Comment: Yeah, I've already done it myself, thats not the case though. Problem is that it doesn't redirect at all because $data is false, so that if statement doesn't run.

Comment: It does redirect indeed but when it does it still says that I've got some items in my cart. When I go to my cart directly from the homepage it says it's empty. Let's just leave it like it was before, without the redirecting. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this code for your error.

```
add_action("template_redirect", 'e_coding_hub_redirection_function');

function e_coding_hub_redirection_function(){

global $woocommerce;
    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
        //wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
    }
}
```